# how to clone a circular JSON in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I know for cloning normal objects we can do:

```
var a = {"fruit":"apple"};

var cloneA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

but this does not work with circular objects. I am new in nodejs any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to clone a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)